# I want to call the start Activity in BroadcastReceiver in android

Tags: android

I want to call the start Activity in BroadcastReceiver in android. I know it is a service and we cant call an activity from a service.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to call the start Activity in BroadcastReceiver in android.

Call `startActivity()` on the `Context` passed in as a parameter.

> I know it is a service

A `BroadcastReceiver` is not a `Service`.

> and we cant call an activity from a service.

Yes, you can call `startActivity()` in a `Service`.

However, calling `startActivity()` from either a `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service` may not be what the *user* wants. You have no idea what the user is doing, and you might be taking over the foreground in the middle of something else. Please only use this in places where the user will value the interruption, or offer alternatives (e.g., a `SharedPreference` to indicate that you should use a `Notification` instead of starting an activity).