# How to call browser in BroadcastReceiver in android

Tags: android

How to call browser in BroadcastReceiver in android? Can any one help me? I tried by using to set flags for intent. It is not coming it saying error

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your `Intent` via the `setFlags()` method.

As I [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957497/hi-i-want-to-call-the-start-activity-in-broadcastreceiver-in-android/6958785#6958785) in [another of your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957497/hi-i-want-to-call-the-start-activity-in-broadcastreceiver-in-android), calling `startActivity()` from a `BroadcastReceiver` may not be what the user wants.